# suppress timestamp from tfs

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I don't want timestamp to appear for a datetime field on Work Item Template on TFS Web Portal. Can you please suggest how can I do that.
An image of work item template with DateTime field is attached for reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/specify-work-item-form-controls?view=tfs-2015#add-date-or-calendar-fields

You need to change the Format to "Short" like:
`xml
<Control Type="DateTimeControl" FieldName="MyCompany.EnvironmentCR.PreferredStart"

Label="Preferred Start Date:" LabelPosition="Left" Format="Short" />`